# How to install a package manually in a React Native project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I am trying to instal a npm package in my React Native project,

```
npm install react-native-threatmetrix --save
```

but I got the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOVERSIONS
npm ERR! No valid versions available for react-native-threatmetrix
```

So, looks like the package has no available version. But I have access to the Github repository (https://github.com/teopeurt/react-native-threatmetrix), and I like to know if there is a way to install packages manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch package from `npm`, first it must be registered with [NPM](https://www.npmjs.org)

The package you have mentioned over here is not registered.

The [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/teopeurt/react-native-threatmetrix) of the same has no release or package. You can check on the link clearly.

You can't get it. Until a release and registration on NPM.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the package has been removed from npm registry.

You can clone the github repo using `git clone https://github.com/teopeurt/react-native-threatmetrix.git`, add it to your `node_modules` folder and then follow the manual instructions provided in the [readme](https://github.com/teopeurt/react-native-threatmetrix#manual-installation).